# Storing CIDR in IP type field in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to store CIDR notations in the IP Address data type in elastic search? When I try to POST them into my index it fails. (singlerange property has ip type)

```
{
  "singlerange": "222.165.0.0/17",
  "name": "Single range"
}
```

Result

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "failed to parse [singlerange]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason": "failed to parse [singlerange]",
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
      "reason": "'222.165.0.0/17' is not an IP string literal."
    }
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

So, ES is telling me 'no' but before I gave up on ES as a tool for this I wanted to see if anyone had a workaround or alternative way of storing and querying ranges.

I know the docs have the use case where you store IPs and query by ranges. Our use case is opposite, we want to store ranges and query the index for any range that contains a specific IP.

Comment: Hmmm, I have not tried to solve this myself, so I don't have a clear answer, but an idea that comes to mind is to precalculate the boundaries of the range upstream and store them in the search index, so each document has a "startingAddress" and "endingAddress".  The rules of CIDR are based on math, so there are really no data maintenance concerns because the ranges will never change unless the CIDR bits change.

Comment: This is where I ended up as well. Pushing top and bottom to the index and then, since they are IP data types, I can query a gte/lte and find any range that my IP is in. Working well so far, we will be doing performance testing tonight and I'll update my answer below with the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, the act of posting to StackOverflow allows me to solve the problem.

What I did is create the range manually on insert like this

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "newrange": {
      "properties": {
        "bottomrange": {
          "type": "ip"
        },
        "toprange": {
          "type": "ip"
        },
        "name": {
           "type": "text"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This lets me insert things like this (in this example I am representing 222.165.0.0/17:

```
{
  "bottomrange": "222.165.0.1",
  "toprange": "222.165.127.254",
  "name": "Single range"
}
```

And thus I can query with filters like this (in this case trying to find a range that matches 222.165.128.99)

```
{
  "query": { 
    "bool": { 
      "filter": [  
        { "range": { "bottomrange": { "lte": "222.165.128.99" }}} ,
        { "range": { "toprange": { "gte": "222.165.128.99" }}} 
      ]
    }
  }
```

}

Voila! Probably not the most efficient ES query ever but its got to be more efficient then a developer loading thousands of CIDR range specifiers into memory in node and iterating through each for a match.. We'll see.

Comment: I bet you that will be a very efficient query actually.

Comment: For `222.165.0.0/17` IP range should be '222.165.0.0' - '222.165.127.255'?

Comment: Correct, bad example on my part, it was to illustrate the query concept rather than be precise on the boundaries. Thanks for the correction.